# adding grub to secure boot signature bricked my pc

Tags: linux, uefi, secure-boot

I have a bought a new pc with a ryzen 7 1700 from MEDION. The PC works well under Windows and Linux with Secure Boot disabled. But the problem came when I wanted to enable grub with secure boot. As I did on my notebook I went to the secure boot settings on SETUP screen and added the grub to the allowed signatures of the secure boot. The problem is that after that the pc only booted the Antergos (an Arch Linux distro) and it couldn't boot any other thing, like a windows 10 cd.

This also happened me some weeks ago, that time I used the warranty of the site where I bought the computer. But now due to the very slow time to proccess the warranty I want to find a solution instead of using the warranty again. Is there anything I could do to restore this computer? Thanks

Comment: No. I want to my computer to boot Linux or Windows, it doesnt matter for me. I have contacted them to ask for help,  I m waiting their reply.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your computer is NOT BRICKED. Bricked implies you cannot restore functionality easily. Go back into the BIOS Utility (using whichever key is appropriate for your motherboard) and disable Secure Boot. You should then be able to boot from any medium your motherboard supports. If worst comes to worst and you cannot disable Secure Boot, use a secondary computer to install an OS with a matching Secure Boot signature onto a hard drive, then use that hard drive to boot on your "bricked" machine.